# Magento 2 Ajax Add to Cart for recently viewed products

Tags: magento-2.2.5

I am struggling with enabling Ajax Add to cart option for recently viewed products.

Currently, the page is reloaded while adding the product to cart. In place of that, I have to use AJAX add to cart option.

I am using Ultimo Theme.

Answer (score 1):

If you getting redirected to the Cart Page after adding, check the settings of '*After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart*' under 
*Store->Configuration->Sales->Checkout*. It should be ideally 'No'

Comment: That already selected No.

Comment: Well in that case, then it would be a custom setting set by Ultimo theme guys!!!